# Getting user to authenticate the password

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a sh coding to get the user to authenticate the password by comparing the user input to the first 32 characters of a file. So basically if the password is correct it would run TaskMenu.csh if its wrong the program would exit.

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
echo -e " Please Enter the Password to access the TaskMenu:"
read PW
if (! -e "$PASSWORD.txt")
then
        echo -n "The file doesn't exist"
        echo kil
        exit
else
        ...(i have no clue what to do)...
```

Please help

Comment: You mention a csh file, your `if` is in the style used by csh, your shebang says sh and your question tags include [bash]. Which is it?

Comment: Why the 32-character maximum?  That's pretty long, but I see no compelling reason to impose such a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$PW" = $(cat "$PASSWORD.txt | head -c 32) ]
then
    ./TaskMenu.csh
else
    echo Authentication failed.
    exit 3
fi
```

Run with `bash -x`, or add `set -x` to the top of your source to see what strings are being passed around.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that you can run this with bash -x (More likely, tcsh -x, but basically the same thing) and get the name of the file containing the password completely invalidate this method for password authentication?

Comment: @reemrevnivek: That's a separate issue.

Comment: I understand that it's not the problem, but wanted to point it out in case a beginner didn't realize this, and tried something like chmod 111'ing the script.  I think I should have made it a statement instead of a question.